# Access attribute of container from member Python

Tags: python, list, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I have a class (`PlayerList`) that contains `Player` objects (or subclasses) by inheriting from `list` builtin. I want each of the `Player` objects to use the container's attribute `true_dice.` The problem is that for testing purposes I need each of the players to have the ability to use their own as well, if they are not part of a `PlayerList`

```
class PlayerList(list):
    def __init__(plist):
        # plist is a list of Player objects
        self.true_dice = [0,0,0,0]
        super().__init__(plist)

class Player:
    def __init__():
        self.true_dice = "<Magical code that gets containers true_dice>"
    
    def turn(self):
        "..."
        self.true_dice[2] = 1 # Modify true_dice should modify PlayerList's aswell
```

What is the pythonic way to achieve this? A google search turns up no results.

I was thinking perhaps overriding `__getattribute__` would work, but then I would have to store a reference to the `PlayerList` in the class, and that is a very tightly coupled solution:

```
class Player:
...
    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
            if attrname=="true_dice":
                return player_list_reference.true_dice # Defined in __init__
            else:
                return self.__dict__[attrname]
```

Or perhaps I could run an update function every time a member of the 'PlayerList' changes its `true_dice` attribute. This would separate concerns rather well...

Please comment any and all requests for edits.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? Is your issue defining the attribute *access* on `Player`, using the `PlayerList` attribute, or falling back to (or preferring?) the `Player`'s own attribute?

Comment: A bit of both I think... I'm on it.

Comment: What is `player_list_reference`? Is this some global attribute, a placeholder for something to be defined, or a mistyped attribute of `Player`?

Comment: If it is for testing purposes, use unittest and mock the attribute or use some other testing framework.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Like I said "but then I would have to store a reference to the PlayerList in the class, and that is a very tightly coupled solution" It is a reference to the container that it is a part of.

Comment: @wwii True, good idea. I need another solution: check my edits.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't set `true_dice` on `Player`? It's a list after all, so changes are seen on all references to it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Not sure exactly what you mean... Set true_dice in the `__init__` method to a reference to it's PlayerList? If so... Great idea, please write up a formal answer.

Comment: 1) `PlayerList` should use composition to store a list of players, rather than inheritance to *be* a list of players. 2) `Player.turn` should take dice as an *argument*, and `PlayerList` should have a method for calling the appropriate `Player's` `turn` method with `self.true_dice` as the argument.

Comment: @chepner 1) Perhaps, it is inheriting from list to make things simpler, it is basically storing them... just in `self` I have thought about that... 2) Not quite, the true_dice is not specific to Players it is a variable that represents something about the game state. The game is Qwixx btw

Answer (score 0):

All credit to @MisterMiyagi, suggested this answer.

He advocated for something like this if I understand correctly.

```
class PlayerList(list):
    def __init__(self, plist):
        # plist is a list of Player objects
        self.true_dice = [False, False, False, False]
        for player in plist:
            player.true_dice = self.true_dice # Set true_dice of members
        super().__init__(plist)

class Player:
    def __init__(self, true_dice=None):
        self.true_dice = true_dice
    def turn(self):
        "..."
        self.true_dice[2] = 1 # Modify true_dice should modify PlayerList's aswell

# Implementation Change, not sure how to make this automatic...
pl = PlayerList([Player()])
```